# API migration, need to request new permissions?

Tags: scope, migration, instagram, instagram-api

The new API introduces a new scope *public_content* that was not mandatory before.

For my app, I need to retrieve some public datas from user view. So I will add *public_content* to my scope, but what about access tokens already generated? I have to log out all my users then ask them to authorize the new *public_content* permission?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to log them out - old access tokens will be expired, so they're already 'logged out'. You should handle scenario with expired access token in the first place, because due to Instagram doc

> Access tokens may expire at any time in the future.

so from user perspective, moving from one API to another will be similar to scenario, when their access tokens had expired.